# d3.js selector not returning actual object

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.js v4. I have executed following code on google chrome browser's console.

```
var theData = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
          .data(theData)
          .enter()
          .append("p")
          .text("hello ");

console.log(p);
```

I  was expecting a result like this:

[image]

But what I am getting is as shown below

[image]

Can someone please help me why this difference is there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to D3 4.x [API](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection):

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

So, in D3 version 4.x, selections *are* objects.

Also, it's worth mentioning that you're using the compressed version (https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js), which returns:

```
zi {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}
```

In the normal version (https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js), the `console.log` return should be:

```
Selection {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}
```

If you want to get something similar to what you had in D3 v3, use `nodes()`:

```js
var theData = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
          .data(theData)
          .enter()
          .append("p")
          .text("hello ");

console.log(p.nodes());
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```